# Why are two empty Lists not Equal?

Tags: c#

I thought calling Equals() on two empty Lists would return true, but that's not the case. Could someone explain why?

```
var lst = new List<Whatever>();
var lst2 = new List<Whatever>();
if(!lst.Equals(lst2))
    throw new Exception("seriously?"); // always thrown
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Equals` here is comparing reference of two lists which would be different because they are separate lists and that's why it will always be false in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I find it silly that collections don't override Equals, for cases like this, if nothing else. Actually, I thought two Lists containing same objects, in same order, would also be equal.

Comment: @VietNorm - that might make sense for two lists of value types, but what if they're more complex reference types? Most reference types in .Net don't override `Equals` as it can produce very confusing behaviour. For instance, what if you had a `Dictionary<List<T>, MyClass>`? How could .Net build the hash based lookup for that class if `List<T>.Equals` was overridden.

Comment: @Keith - I don't understand your question. If List<T> would override Equals(), so that its return depends on the contents of the list, it would override GetHashCode() in a similar manner, obviously.

Comment: @VietNorm that would be very difficult to do unless you know what the type of the list is - `List<T>.GetHashCode()` would need to know what `T` was. You couldn't just check the length of the list, you've need to create a hash for each item in the list and combine them in a way that doesn't cancel out.

Answer (score 8):

Because [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is checking for references - `lst` and `lst2` are different objects. (note that Equals is inherited from `Object` and not implemented in `List<T>`)

You're looking for Linq's [`SequenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx).
Even when using `SequenceEquals`, don't expect it to work with your `Whatever` class on non-empty lists (unless it is a struct). You may want to implement a [comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx), and use the [right overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Object documentation (MSDN documentation):

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference equality means the object references that are compared refer to the same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have the same binary representation.

List documentation (MSDN documentation):

> Determines whether the specified Object is equal to the current Object. (Inherited from Object.)

You have two different objects (two times new ...) so there not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Because it compares on object identity, not the contents of the list.  They are two separate objects.

See this [answer](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#equals) from the C# FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

The `Equals` implementation of `List<T>` is the inherited one from `Object`:

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types

In other words, since these are two *different* lists, they have *different* references, so `Equals` returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>.Equals()` will compare the references of the two lists and return true if they are equal. If you want to compare the elements of two lists, use `List<T>.SequenceEquals()`

Answer (score 1):

When you compare 2 lists with each other, the equals method will NOT compare the items that are in that list. It will just compare the List object with the other List object. these have their own '**identity**'.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the documentation .Equals on List is the inherited method from Object which means it checks if the lists are the same object. Since you have made two object they will not be the same.

Comment: An explanation of why down vote would be nice so I knew how to improve.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote either. The fact that List doesn't override Equals() is the essence of all correct answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different lists allocated somewhere in memory (with new keyword). Therefore they cannot be equal. If you want such functionality you should build your own object inheriting from List and overriding Equals function

Answer (score 0):

In C# and .Net you have reference types and value types.

Value types represent, well, values. `integer`, `double`, `DateTime` and so on.

When you compare value types you compare their actual value, so:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 10;

if( a == b ) 
{
    // this will fire
}
```

Note that each variable refers to a new copy, so:

```
int c = a;
c = c+5;

if( a == c ) 
{
    // this won't, because a==10 and c==15
}
```

Reference types are objects that you pass around a do things with. You can have more than one variable referring to the the same object, so:

```
var a = new List<Whatever>();
var b = new List<Whatever>();
if( a == b ) 
{
    // this won't fire, a and be are separate objects
}

var c = a;
c.Add(new Whatever());
if( a == c ) 
{
    // this will, a and c are the same object.
    a[0]; // holds the value added to c
}
```

Finally some special cases of reference types behave like value types, for instance `string`.

Answer (score -1):

Two different things cant be the same, even if these things got the same items (or are  both empty).

You dont need to be good at programing to understand this ;) Lets say you have a **this** and **that**, its not important whats inside **this** and **that**. Its just important that a **this** is not a **that** or a **that** is not a **this**. Thats what you you check there with `equals`

Comment: Ok maybe its because of my english but for me a refence of two things is still not equal. And thats why hes getting the exception. But if you think this and that is the same of the reference...ok :) BUT we need then an example. Thank you

Comment: I understand what's going on very well, I just don't find it intuitive at all. I tried the same thing with Java, after asking the question here, and Java's Equals() behaves in a way I find intuitive - it returns true if lists are empty (and also if they have equal objects, in same order). So, Java designers are, like me, "not good at programming" ;)  If I wanted to check for reference equality, I'd call ReferenceEquals(), not Equals().